# How to initialize TypeFace in an interface class

Tags: android, interface, android-typeface

So i have this interface :

```
public interface Utils{
    static final Typeface FONT = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/font.ttf");;
}
```

I am having an error in `getAssets()`, it says **The method getAssets() is undefined for the type Utils** why is that? Please help thanks :)

Comment: What is the exact error? And what is your motivation for doing this?

Comment: see edit @Code-Guru tnx :)

Comment: The error is quite clear. `Utils` does not have a method named `getAssets()`.

Comment: What is the purpose of what you are trying to do?

Comment: i want to implement this interface to the other activities that i created so i wont have recode the TypeFace all over again.

Comment: Utils is just the name of the interface @Code-Guru

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Utils` class does not have a method named `getAssets()`. I assume you want to use the one from the Android `Context` class. This means you need to have a `Context` object to call `getAssets()`. Without more details about your exact app design, I can't help you any further.

One possible solution is to create an `Activity` subclass which all of your other activities extend. You also need to honor the activity life-cycle:

```
public abstract FontActivity extends Activity {

    private Typeface font;

    @Override
    public onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/font.ttf");
    }

}
```

Now extend `FontActivity` instead of `Activity`.

Comment: This interface i created will be implemented on Activity classes that needs the FONT that i need. Its a seperate class by the way. Thanks though :)

Comment: @GreenFox The `Utils` interface knows *nothing* about the methods defined in `Activity` and its superclasses.

Comment: so i cannot use this kind of approach? hence i cannot initialize the TypeFace if it wasn't in an Activity? @Code-Guru

Comment: @GreenFox If you need to call `getAssets()`, you *must* have some kind of `Context` to call it on. The easiest way to do this, IMO, is during an `Activity`'s life-cycle event, such as in `onCreate()`.

Comment: I am quite agreed @Code-Guru

Comment: @Williams Show your agreement with an upvote please ;-)

Comment: This is quite right but id rather create a TypeFace in my MainActivity and make it static final so i can use it in other different activity, than creating another abstract class and extend it on my activity that needs the that font. Thanks though, i will accept this as the right answer it can be a help to other programmers :)

Comment: @GreenFox After reviewing this Q&A, I see that you *can* make the `TypeFace` `static` in `MainActivity`. However, you cannot make it `final` because you must initialize it during `onCreate()`.